# Trying to run Flask on Apache: error 13 (search permissions missing)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to get a test Flask app running on my Ubuntu 16.04 / Apache 2.4 server, and I keep getting `403` errors when requesting pages.

The logs show the following:

```
[Wed Aug 17 10:13:39.782920 2016] [core:error] [pid 30612:tid 140294142019328] (13)Permission denied: [client 131.180.174.104:57481] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/leon/opendc-production/web-server/opendc.wsgi') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: https://opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl/
```

I found the [(13) Permission Denied](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) page on Apache's website and followed the steps, doing `sudo chmod 644 opendc.wsgi`, `sudo chmod 644 hello.py`, and `sudo chmod 644 hello.pyc`, as well as `sudo chmod +x .` and `cd ..` all the way down.

I'm still getting the same "search permissions are missing on a component of the path" error.

Here's the output of ls -al in the `web-server` directory:

```
drwxrwx--- 3 leon leon  4096 Aug 17 10:36 .
drwxrwx--- 7 leon leon  4096 Aug 17 10:21 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 leon leon    93 Aug 16 14:13 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 leon leon   106 Aug 16 15:41 hello.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 leon leon   419 Aug 16 15:45 hello.pyc
-rw-rw---- 1 leon leon 54044 Aug 16 14:13 openapi-spec.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 leon leon    37 Aug 17 10:36 opendc.wsgi
-rw-rw---- 1 leon leon   410 Aug 16 14:13 README.md
drwxrwx--- 6 leon leon  4096 Aug 16 15:40 venv
```

Here's the contents of `opendc.wsgi`:

```
from hello import app as application
```

Here's the contents of `hello.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return 'Hello, OpenDC!'
```

Here's the contents of my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        # Meta

        ServerAdmin l.overweel@gmail.com
        ServerName opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl:443

        # SSL

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /root/opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/DigiCertCA.crt

        # WSGI Python app

        WSGIDaemonProcess opendc user=leon group=adm threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/leon/opendc-production/web-server/opendc.wsgi

        <Directory /home/leon/opendc-production/web-server>
                WSGIProcessGroup opendc
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Another thing to note is that I followed the [Flask installation guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/), so I have python in a `virtualenv`, which I've never used before. Don't know if that changes anything or if I'm supposed to do anything differently because of that.

I also found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678826/trying-to-set-up-flask-with-mod-wsgi) and followed the advice in there, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Look at this http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/ Have you tried to give the permissions using 'Order allow,deny
Allow from all' ?

Comment: @SteevenBrunner yep, that's what I had originally. Just changed it back to that to try again, and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache runs as a special user. If your files are under your home directory it will not be able to read them. Better to move them outside of your home directory. Otherwise you have to do `chmod o+rx` on all directories down to where files are located, which goes against what your OS has setup for you.

Comment: Ah, ok. So what's a good place to put them? `/var/www/project-name`?

Comment: And why doesn't it run as `user=leon group=adm` like I specified in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl.conf`?

Comment: Moving the project to `/var/www/opendc.ewi.tudelft.nl/web-server` and going through the steps on the [(13) Permission Denied error page](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: The mapping of URL to the filesystem path is still done by the Apache user in the Apache child worker process, prior to making a decision to route the request to the mod_wsgi daemon process, which would then load and run your code. You could have left it under your home directory if you had put at least a WSGI script file outside of your home directory, with that WSGI script then importing the WSGI application module from inside of your home directory.